# iptables allow all connections to any port on given machine from any port of a given IP

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I have two machines B and A ; I want to allow all types of traffic on all ports on A from B while disallowing any communication from some other given subnet machines.

What i have done : 
on A :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <subnet to block> -j REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <subnet to block> -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s <B's IP> -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d <B's IP> -j ACCEPT
```

I saved and reloaded using `netfilter.persistent reload`

but B is unable to hit machine A on health port X (20000) on which a service is running on A. I am taking care of first match rule here. When I flush the iptables, it is able to hit the api on port 20000. How can i fix or debug this issue?

Comment: An `iptables-save` would be much more helpful than an unordered subset of rules...

Comment: Also is B in the subnet you're blocking? You mention `another given subnet` and yet without rules blocking it, you shouldn't need to explicitly allow it (unless your policy is to DROP).

Comment: @Ginnungagap yes, B is in the subnet that i am blocking. But I am adding ACCEPT rule in the chain before the REJECT all rule. So, I guess, it should work with the first match rule.

Comment: Then as per @AlexanderTolkachev, it should work, either by reordering rules for clarity or leaving them as-is. Unless we can see a complete set of applied rules, you're on your own.